# max with distinct in sql

Tags: sql

I have a table with rows/data in the following structure

[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UnNyy.jpg)

I want a query that results in the red line(max credit no)

I have tried these:

```
SELECT   employee no, MAX(credit no)
FROM     mytable
GROUP BY employee no

SELECT  distinct employee no, MAX(credit no)
FROM     mytable
GROUP BY employee no
```

but it doesn't give me the red line records

Comment: Show us what it does give you.  Also do not post data as images, please post them as text.

Comment: shouldn't the 1st query give you correct result? can you put the result for your 1st query?

Comment: MAX gives the highest value (in the group), not the full record *having* that max value

Answer (score 0):

You can use correlated subquery :

```
select mt.*
from mytable mt
where mt.creditno = (select max(mt1.creditno) 
                     from mytable mt1 
                     where mt1.employeeno = mt.employeeno
                    );
```

Answer (score 0):

You sould use group by and order by clouse. if you want to just top 2 employee_no, write to select top 2

```
select employee_no, max(credit_no) as max_credit_no from yourtable group by employee_no order by max_credit_no desc

select top 2, employee_no, max(credit_no) as max_credit_no from yourtable group by employee_no order by max_credit_no desc
```

Answer (score 0):

if I understand correctly, I would use the line number to sort the values in descending order then select the lines.

```
 CREATE TABLE #data
( 
   employee_no int,
   credit_no int,
   stat nvarchar(3)
) 

INSERT INTO #data
  (employee_no, credit_no, stat)
VALUES
  (100022, 244, 'ret'),
  (100022, 245, 'emp'),
  (100023, 244, 'vac'),
  (100023, 245, 'ret'),
  (100023, 246, 'emp')*/
```

And select:

```
select * 
  from (
    select employee_no, 
           credit_no, 
           stat, 
           ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by employee_no order by credit_no desc) id
    from #data
  )x
  where id = 1
```

And result:
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=2b97f6e553231a6a9524b143e730f323